# Function prepare query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, bindparam

I'm doing, or trying to do, a database project for the university, but when registering a user this error appears:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in (...)

Initially I wrote

```
$insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO customer (name, email, phonenumber, adress, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?");
```

But then I changed to well, you can see in the code.

```
<?php
require 'db/connect.php';
require 'functions/security.php';

if(!empty($_POST)) {

    if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['password'])) {

        $name = trim($_POST['name']);
        $email `enter code here` = trim($_POST['email']);
        $phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
        $address = trim($_POST['address']);
        $password  = trim($_POST['password']);

        if(!empty($name) && !empty($email) &&!empty($phone) && !empty($address) &&!empty($password)){
                $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO customer VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?");
                $insert->bind_param('ssiss', $name, $email, $phone, $address, $password);
                //$insert->close();

            if($insert->execute()){
                print_r("Done");
                die();
            }            
        }        
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You've got a syntax error on your prepare line. You need to include a bracket after the last question mark.

Comment: If you're going to trim all your post fields you can do: $_POST = array_map("trim",$_POST);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind\_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call to a member function in query's means that the query couldn't get executed because it contains an error.

In this case, you didn't closed the VALUES (). 
Change `$insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO customer VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?");` to `$insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO customer VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");`

Make sure you do check if an error could get executed. 
Example of checking if an query could get executed:

```
$query = $this->_db->prepare("SELECTTEST name FROM user"); //.. Bad query (false)
if(!$query) //.. If the query is false.
{
     trigger_error('Query couldn\'t get executed');
}
```

If this solved your error, I will really appreciate that you vote my answer as answer.